# SQL - Linq/EF/Lambda

Tags: sql

I have a table timestamp and a pable project.

I need all projects where the colum "Finished == false" with the last generated timestamp.

My currrent code:

```
 var result = from p in _contextProvider.Context.Projects
                     join t in _contextProvider.Context.Timestamps on p.Guid equals t.GuidProject
                     where p.Finished == false
                     orderby t.End
                     select new { p.Name, t.End };
```

How to make a "max(t.Enc) group by Projects" ?
PS: Sorry for my bad title, but I don't know which syntax i use :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is tricky question. Here is how you would do it in SQL and it is relatively easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM Projects p
JOIN Timestamps t ON p.Guid = t.GuidProject
WHERE p.Finshed = FALSE AND
 t.END = (
    SELECT max(t1.END)
    FROM Projects p1
    JOIN Timestamps t1 ON p1.Guid = t1.GuidProject
    WHERE p.Finshed = FALSE AND p.Guid = p1.Guid
 )
```

Converting it to Linq will be trickier. This is what I tried, but I could not test it.

```
        var baseQuery = _contextProvider.Context.Projects
                .Join(_contextProvider.Context.Timestamps, p => p.Guid, t => t.GuidProject, (p, t) => new {p, t})
                .Where(o => o.p.Finished == false);

        var result = baseQuery.Select
            .Where(o => o.t.End == baseQuery
                            .Where(o2 => o2.p == o.p)
                            .Select(o2 => o2.t.End)
                            .Max()
                   ).Select( o => new {o.p.Name, o.t.End} );
```

May be I overcomplicated it a bit and it can be achieved with `group by`, try something like this:

```
        var result = (from p in _contextProvider.Context.Projects
                      join t in _contextProvider.Context.Timestamps on p.Guid equals t.GuidProject
                      where p.Finished == false
                      group t.End by p.Name into g
                      select new { name=g.Key, end=g.Max()} );
```

Comment: But then I get only one row. I need one row for each project.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty solution you could try to order descending by t.End and then taking only the top 1/first-or-default result.